# Detect when SearchController is appeared in UINavigationItem

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem with appearing `NavigationController` and `SearchController`. How can I detect when the searchController is presented? I just tried `navigationItem.searchController?.isBeingPresented`, but it didn't work it shows me always false. I tried `isActive`, but it shows me false too.

I have to do that because when I pushing `ViewControllers` in `NavigationControllers` it makes ugly hiding animation... I have one ViewController inside them, there is a SearchController when I click on an item it shows me new ViewController where is SearchController too.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I solved it. You can take `navigationItem.searchController?.searchBar.frame.height` it shows you when searchController is appeared or not.